# How to prevent UIButton from exceeding its parent UIView's width with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language

Is that possible to create a MaxWidth constraint to prevent UIButton from exceeding its parent UIView's width?

UIButton is created programmatically and centered horizontally in its parent UIView using `V:[ParentView]-(<=1)-[Button]` constraint, but when the text is too large, button's width exceeds ParentView.

**NOTE**: I do not want to add leading/trailing constraints, which will force the button always be the same width as the parent. I really need the button to be center horizontally so when the text is short, it will not cover the whole width.

Comment: add leading/trailing constraints from button to `UIView`

Comment: You can refer to this: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutconstraint

Comment: @JuicyFruit I think I cant do that, adding leading/trailing constraints will force the button always be the same width as the parent. I really need the button to be center horizontally so when the text is short, it will not cover the whole width.

Comment: you should use `>=0`

Comment: @JuicyFruit would you visualize the whole VFL constraint, as I am a newbie ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your `button`'s `widthAnchor` to be less than or equal to its `parentView`'s `widthAnchor`:

```
button.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: parentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
```